# linux: best way to wrap a in-the-clear protocol in ssh

Tags: linux, security, ssh, sshd

I've got a legacy protocol, no support for authentication, no support for sessions, just plain and simple do whatever you want commands which are sent in the clear from client to server and the server happily executes whatever it receives much as ron burgundy reads from the auto-cue..

One solution is to reimplement the legacy service with tls.  This would work but it could be a world of pain and i'm hoping to find something easier.  I know the arguments to prefer tls to ssh, in this case there are also arguments to prefer an easy big improvement to a bigger riskier reimplementation that is a marginal improvement over the easy win.

I'm thinking to:

- create a 'protocol-user' with /etc/passwd shell=/usr/bin/legacy-protocol-handler
- the client sends a command by connecting via ssh and writing the command to the shell
- sshd executes the protocol handler (the users shell) and passes the command
- the protocol handler processes the command and sends back the response, hangs up
- sshd marshalls the response and sends across the network
- this solves authentication & transport encryption and I've hardly changed code in the protocol handler

This general idea could be even easier than above, the unix user system is only being used to execute a custom protocol handler instead of a shell..  I couldnt find a command that would listen on a port, do the authentication/encryption heavy lifting, and execute a protocol handler for each connection e.g. 
ssh-listen --port 1224 --accept-only-this-user publickey.bin --execute /usr/bin/legacy-protocol-handler

The questions:

- is this a reasonable solution (it seems like i'm not using sshd as intended ..)
- what are the drawbacks of this approach
- is there a better way of getting respectable security for similar effort
- is there a similar approach where i can use a tls listener instead of passing through sshd

Comment: IMHO TLS is no more painful that ssh

Comment: is there a tls-deamon infrastructure I can plug into in the same way that I can plug into ssh / sshd ?

Comment: I've used stunnel in the past - it's easy to set up and reliable. Stud works the same and should be more scalable, but I've not used it myself.